# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

User Experience's [3rd moderator election](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Michael Lai]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5666528506675200/0).

Comment: Congrats, @michael-lai!

Comment: congrats man, well deserved :)

Comment: Well done Michael!

Comment: Congratulations Michael !

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the team! About time we had some fresh blood around the place.

Comment: Very honored and excited to be joining the team! There's a lot to learn but I am grateful for the opportunity to serve the community that I have been part of for the last few years of my professional career, and the learning experience it will provide :)

Comment: Congrats Michael! :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the UX Mod team! You’re an excellent representative of our community, and I know you will make us better!